# Google Sheets error with Index / Match using multiple criteria

Tags: google-sheets

I am having issues with finding a value based on multiple index / match criteria.
I have tried a ton of variations including ...
match(1,(blah=blah)*(... 
and 
match(A&B,Sheet1A2:A&Sheet2A2:A... 
Can someone please look at it and give a bit of guidance? 
I have included notes in the sheet for reference: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1U7Zwj4uPSCg1wOsYsJcKd9Cvu9RJUObdspcDeD04E3A/edit?usp=sharing
Thanks!

Comment: =ArrayFormula(if(isblank(A3:A)=true," ",INDEX(D3:F,MATCH(1,(D3:D=A3:A)*(B3:B=$H$1)*(E3:E=$H$1),0),3)))
Gives Error: Did not find value '1' in MATCH evaluation; I had researched this problem and cannot get it to work.

Comment: the master sheet that I am using is indexing about 30k rows which I believe I'd get at least one 'true' from; I am doing something wrong with the formula and have searched the 'net to all ends and still I'm just missing something super small.

Comment: thank you for the clarification, i will attempt vlookup again with the multiple variables first, if not then i will drag down ... i was hoping that with an array(isblank) it could have been worked around instead of dragging

Comment: thank you @|'-'| for validating my formula, I already had this: =if(isblank(A3:A)=true," ",INDEX(D3:F,MATCH(1,($D$3:$D=A3)*(B3:B=$H$1),0),3)) .. it will work if I want to drag down, unfortunately I can have up to 500k rows in a project so I'm trying to do a workaround to autofill.  I'd try this in JS but I am too green and would probably take longer for me to learn and implement.

Comment: I am confused how so? It keeps saying "out of range". I have right now =ArrayFormula(if(isblank(A3:A)=true," ",vlookup(A3:A&$H$1,$D$3:D&F3:$F,3,true))) So in this case I believe it's because I am looking up two columns and wanting a 3rd ... actually it does the same with column 2 also.

Comment: Sorry, I'm still a bit green and try to learn it first before asking but right now I've had information overload and it made me confused.

Comment: That worked great, thank you. I see my problem was the "{ }" and putting the F:F column within the squigglies. I never worked with those before and just recently came across a page on that ... thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @I'-'I for the answer. 
=arrayformula(vlookup(a:a&b:b,{d:d&e:e,f:f},2,0)) – I'-'I 
... I was missing the "{ }" and adding the additional F:F column which is why the error was saying 'out of bounds range'.